# Incorporating ActionListener to MouseMotionListener in java

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener, mouselistener

How can I incorporate the `actionPerformed()` to `mouseMoved()`?

This is my code:

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
if(e.getSource()==app.p1){
        ????
}

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
if(e.getSource()==b1)
    ????
}
```

b1 is a JButton which says "red" and p1 is a panel which is colored with blue.
I want a result that when I click b1, I would get a color. And when I move my mouse to p1, p1 will change color from blue to red. How do I do this.

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Something like:

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
if(e.getSource()==app.p1){
    //get the color stored in the variable and set it as background
}

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
if(e.getSource()==b1)
    //get color and store it in like a variable
}
```

I can't directly do this because p1 will be filled without moving the mouse over it:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
if(e.getSource()==b1)
    p1.setBackground(Color.RED);
}
```

Comment: So you want `actionPerformed` to be called instead of `mouseMoved` when the mouse is moved?

Comment: i think you need mouseEnter and not MouseMove

Comment: No. I mean. When I click b1, b1 will give the color of p1 when the mouse is moved over p1.

Comment: what color? what do you mean "give color"? random color?

Comment: @NoIdeaForName I think he wants the text on the button to determine color, and not have the panel change until the mouse moves over it.

Comment: @Cruncher o_O but a fixed color? like putting a flag or something?

Comment: @Cruncher exactly. I edited my question to be clearer.

Comment: i've edited the answer, lemme know if it's good for you

Comment: It would be easier to understand your code and help you if it were a SSCCE: http://sscce.org

Comment: You shouldn't have deleted your last question, I was just about to answer it.

Comment: @peeskillet Oh I'm so sorry. Well, I posted a new question. I'm close to achieving what I want. Take a look if it doesn't bother you: [Plot points using paint(g) and run()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431122/plot-points-using-paintg-and-run)

Answer (score 1):

Instance Variable:

```
String colorString = ""
```

Event handlers:

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==app.p1){
        app.p1.setBackground(Color.getColor(this.colorString));
    }
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource()==b1)
        this.colorString = e.getActionCommand();
    }
}
```

This uses the text on the button to determine color. Note that if the String is an invalid color name it won't work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and give you some feedback.

Comment: Well, I tried it but it seems to be not working. I can understand how the code lines work but p1 changes color(same color with the frame, not red) by moving the mouse over it even without clicking b1. Can you give an alternate solution for this.

Comment: I got it, I edited the answer of @NoIdeaForName. Thanks anyways. gj

Answer (score 1):

first define a flag in the class

```
   public boolean isBtnClicked = false;
```

and now add actionListener as you want

```
   b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            isBtnClicked = true;
        }
    });
```

and the same with mouse events

```
P1.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        if(isBtnClicked)
        {
           b1.setBackground(Color.RED);
           isBtnClicked = false;
        }
    }
    //Other overriden methods
    ...
});
```

Comment: I edited your answer and it finally worked. Thanks a lot, bro. :)