# Plot points using paint(g) and run()

Tags: java, user-interface, paint, runnable

What I want to do is once I pressed the button "GO", it will paint/draw 3 ovals with different coordinates. I've tried repainting but seems it doesn't work. It only shows one oval which is the last oval. I want it to stack up and append the ovals.

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.Graphics; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JButton button;
int[] itoken;
int x,y;

public Test() {
super("Test");
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.setSize(600,500);
this.setVisible(true);
this.setResizable(true);
this.setLayout(null);

button= new JButton("GO");
button.setBounds(500, 100, 50,50);

this.add(button);
button.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
    if(e.getSource()==button){
        String text= "200 300 250 150 400 100";
        String[] token= text.split("\\W");
        itoken= new int[token.length];
        int i=0;
        for (String str : token){
            itoken[i++] = Integer.parseInt(str);
        }
        for(i=0; i<itoken.length; i++)
        System.out.println(itoken[i]);
    run();
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
        g.drawOval(x - 5, y - 5, 10, 10);
}   

public void run(){
    int i=0;        
    while(i<itoken.length-1){
        repaint();
        x=itoken[i];
        y=itoken[i+1];
        i++;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test(); 
}
}
```

Comment: this here? `y=itoken[i+1];`? Try `while (i < itoken.length -1)`

Comment: @tobias_k Nice bro. thanks. Well, now i need to know how to stack up the ovals. there are 6 coordinates so it should have 3 ovals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** - I was working on this answer right before you deleted your previous question, so the answer may see a little off in terms of the new code you posted in *this* question, but it gets you towards the same goal.

1. Don't initialize everthing in the `actionPerformed`. You're getting a `NullPointerException` because `paint` is called by the frame implicitly before the array is initialized. What I did was create a method to initialize it

   ```
   int[] iToken = initArray();
   ...
   private int[] initArray() {
        String text = "200 300 250 150 400 100";
        String[] token = text.split("\\W");
        int[] itoken = new int[token.length];
        int i = 0;

        for (String str : token) {
            itoken[i++] = Integer.parseInt(str);
        }

        return itoken;
   }
   ```
2. Don't paint on top level containers like `JFrame`. Instead us a `JPanel` or `JCompoent` and override `paintComponent`, and override `getPreferredSize()` in your `JPanel` so you *won't* have to set the size of your `JFrame`. Just `pack()` it.
3. Run Swing apps from the [**Event Dispatch Thread**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) like this

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilitiies.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
           public void run(){
               new Test();
           }
       });
   }
   ```
4. You never add your button to the frame.
5. Don't use a null layout. Use [**Layout Managers**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).
6. Add you components, *then* call `setVisible`

---

Here's the running refactored code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton button;
    boolean paint = false;
    int x, y;
    int[] iToken = initArray();

    public Test() {

        super("Test");

        button = new JButton("GO");
        button.setBounds(500, 100, 50, 50);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(new DrawPanel());

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == button) {
            paint = true;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private int[] initArray() {
        String text = "200 300 250 150 400 100";
        String[] token = text.split("\\W");
        int[] itoken = new int[token.length];
        int i = 0;
        for (String str : token) {
            itoken[i++] = Integer.parseInt(str);
        }
        return itoken;
    }

    public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            if (paint) {
                for (int i = 0; i < iToken.length; i += 2) {
                    x = iToken[i];
                    y = iToken[i + 1];
                    g.drawOval(x - 5, y - 5, 10, 10);
                }
            }
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(500, 500);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: dude, youre just freakin awesome. learned a lot from your code. love you no homo. srs.
btw, paint() is used for frame while paintComponent() is used for panel. am i right?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Though `JPanel` _has_ a `paint` method, you'll should call `paintComponent` instead.

Comment: Oh and I had a typo in the code. `y = iToken[i + 1];` is what you need instead of `y = iToken[2];`